# SQL запрос выборки диапазонов дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите составить SQL запрос..

Есть таблица с датами:

```
id |   date     | startTime | endTime
---+------------+-----------+--------
 1 | 2018-06-02 |   00:00   |  02:00
 2 | 2018-06-02 |   02:00   |  04:00
 3 | 2018-06-02 |   18:00   |  19:00
 4 | 2018-06-02 |   21:30   |  22:00
```

Нужно достать из нее записи, которые затрагивают входящую дату.

Например входящая **2018-06-02 15:00-17:00** не вернет ни одной, а
**2018-06-02 18:00-21:40** вернет **3** и **4** записи. Спасибо.

Comment: вы дату именно в таком формате "2018-06-02 15:00-17:00" в запрос хотите передавать?

Comment: Да, входящая приходит такой, но это не страшно, предварительно ее можно распарсить на 3 параметра: date, startTime и endTime

Comment: формируйте нормальный datetime из всего что юзаете

Comment: зачем дату и время разбивать на 3 колонки ? можно же использовать DATETIME или timestamp ! это извращение

Comment: dateTime ок, но проект старый и там именно так сделано, менять слишком затратно и могут быть баги в других местах

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из вариантов решения - будет работать только если начало \ конец периода за одну дату будет:

```
select * from test where date = '2018-06-02' and startTime < '21:40' and endTime > '18:00';
```

Здесь первое значение - конец запрашиваемого периода, второе - начало.

Пример можно погонять вот [здесь.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d75abf/4)

Да, решение указано из предположения, что строки выводятся при пересечении интервала запроса и интервала в самой строчке таблицы. То есть при запросе с 18:30 до 21:40 тоже будут выводиться те же строчки.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InputData NVARCHAR(22) = '2018-06-02 18:00-21:40'
DECLARE @InputDate DATE = SUBSTRING(@InputData, 1,10)
DECLARE @InputTimeFrom TIME = SUBSTRING(@InputData, 12,5)
DECLARE @InputTimeTo TIME = SUBSTRING(@InputData, 18,22)

DECLARE @DataTable TABLE (id INT, date_column DATE, startTime TIME, endTime 
TIME)
INSERT INTO @DataTable(id, date_column, startTime, endTime) VALUES
(1 , '2018-06-02' , '00:00' , '02:00'),
(2 , '2018-06-02' , '02:00' , '04:00'),
(3 , '2018-06-02' , '18:00' , '19:00'),
(4 , '2018-06-02' , '21:30' , '22:00')

SELECT *
FROM @DataTable
WHERE date_column = @InputDate 
AND startTime BETWEEN @InputTimeFrom AND @InputTimeTo
```

Если поля типа varchar к этому типу нужно привести и переменные